# How to read any STL ASCII formatted file without knowing the format?

Tags: parsing, fortran, fortran90, stl-format

I'm writing a program to read data from different ASCII formatted STL files. The data of this kind of files follows this pattern

```
facet normal n1 n2 n3
    outer loop
        vertex v1x v1y v1z
        vertex v2x v2y v2z
        vertex v3x v3y v3z
    endloop
endfacet
```

The only way I've managed to read this was using a varying-length character array, which works for all formats. However, I'm going to need this data to perform calculations, which would not work if I'm using character variables to store the data, right?
My question is how can I convert the array elements to real numbers?

For example, after I've read these lines

```
  facet normal 0 -1 0
      outer loop
          vertex 0.83404 0 0.694596
          vertex 0.36904 0 1.5
          vertex 1.78814e-006 0 0.75
      endloop
  endfacet
```

with using character arrays, is is possible to convert their value to real? If so, which format should I choose to minimize numerical errors when I use these values in calculations ?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need character arrays, use strings. You can read numbers from a string. We have many examples here. You just need to determine where in the string is the number.

Comment: Maybe not a dupe, but read this anyway - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738862/how-to-iterate-over-character-strings-with-numbers-words-and-blancks-in-fortran/57747281

Comment: Ha, ha, ha, ha - I now realise that the Q&A I cross-referenced was asked by the same person as asked this question :-))