# How to read data from ASCII STL file as a character array and convert it to real numbers?

Tags: arrays, stl, fortran, character, ascii

I'm writing a Fortran program that reads information from an ASCII STL file and writes it into another file.

The structure of the file is as follows:

```
solid model
    facet normal n1 n2 n3
        outer loop
            vertex v1x v1y v1z
            vertex v2x v2y v2z
            vertex v3x v3y v3z
        endloop
    endfacet
    facet normal n1' n2' n3'
        outer loop
            vertex v1x' v1y' v1z'
            vertex v2x' v2y' v2z'
            vertex v3x' v3y' v3z'
        endloop
    endfacet
    .
    .repeats 
    .
    endsolid
```

In other words, the files consists of an unknown number of triangular facets, each containing the information in the pattern shown above.

I'm using character allocatable character arrays to get around having to specify the format of the input file, since it varies and I have no control over it.

This is necessary because I have no way of knowing in advance the precise format of each file being read, since they're not always the same.

Also, in this file format, I have no way of knowing the number of facets that each file contains in advance.

So far, the strategy I used to read the files was declaring an array of characters as

```
   character(len=:), dimension(:), allocatable :: line
```

and allocating and deallocating the number of positions I need available on each line, since they vary.

If I understand it correctly, my problem is that I'm unable to allocate the positions of the array 'line' without specifying the length of each position. But I don't in fact know the length I need to allocate each position in advance. For example, in this file I have this facet:

```
facet normal 0.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
   outer loop
      vertex 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
      vertex 1.500000e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
      vertex 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 5.000000e+01
   endloop
endfacet
```

while in another I have (Note that in this file 'outer loop' is written in the next line beginning only 1 space after 'facet normal'; in the first file, there were 3 spaces):

```
facet normal -0.962637 0.19148 0.19148
 outer loop
  vertex 1.96194 0 1.30866
  vertex 2.03806 0.191342 1.5
  vertex 1.9971 0.191342 1.29409
 endloop
endfacet
```

*) How could I read any file format using character arrays? Is it even possible?

2) For example, if I try

```
  allocate(character(len=*) :: line(5))
```

I get the error:

```
 allocate(character(len=*) :: line(5))

 internal compiler error: in gfc_trans_allocate, at fortran/trans-stmt.c:5697

 1face.f90:27:0: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6
 gfortran: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 (program f951)
 Please submit a full bug report,
 with preprocessed source if appropriate.
 See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

3) If I try

```
 allocate(character(len=:) :: line(5))
```

I get

```
 allocate(character(len=:) :: line(5))
         1
 Error: Type-spec at (1) cannot contain a deferred type parameter
```

4) I've tried using real formats for the reading, but it doesn't work.
If I try using an real allocatable variable and allocate it

```
 real, dimension(:), allocatable :: line
 allocate(line(5))
```

my compiler doesn't complain, but this variable reads junk from the file: For the same example above, I get

```
4.15787011E+21   1.24145785E+28   2.73757760E+20   4.00465633E-11   4.00463551E-11
```

5) Finally, I've tried reading the information as a character array as

```
read(unit=iunit, iostat=ios) line
```

which works fine, but after the reading, I need to perform calculations with the data. So I'm thinking I could convert it to a real one-dimension array, correct?

I've tried reading the line using the character allocatable array

```
read(iunit, iostat=ios) line
```

and writing its contents in a real allocatable array (3 dimension real_line) using

```
write(line,*) real_line
```

but then I get

```
Fortran runtime error: End of record
```

With that in mind, could someone help me? What should I do? Should I:

- Stick with the character reading and try to convert the data to real numbers in another way?
- Try something else?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Your code does not use the very old Fortran 90 anyway. There were no allocatable character strings in Fortran 90.

Comment: The code I posted to answer your earlier question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57738862/how-to-iterate-over-character-strings-with-numbers-words-and-blancks-in-fortran - answers this question.  I'll leave it to someone else to vote to close this duplicate in case I'm missing some subtlety about this version.

Comment: Hey, Mark! I've seen your post, but I've never been able to implement what you suggested, due to my ignorance. My compiler complains about "Unexpected data declaration statements" all over. The types you described should be declared inside a main program? Or inside the function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Marcelo: look at this from my point of view: you've asked essentially the same question 4 times now since last August.  Each version is another stab in the dark at sorting out a piece of code to read an STL file.  You don't seem to be learning anything, I can't see any evidence that you have made a serious effort to solve your own problem, either by getting the code I offered in my answer to your original question to work, or by any other means.  SO is here to help, not to do your work for you.

Comment: And I now see, in your comment on that earlier question, that you write *I've managed to fix my program and now I'm able to read any STL file correctly*  so why are you still asking this question ?

Comment: Because my program only reads the characters from the file, but doesn't store the information read in a real matrix, which will be needed afterwards. That's my current problem.

Comment: Also, I'm now currently trying to implement the code you suggested, and dealing with the necessary type conversions.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I would use

```
implicit none
integer ii
character*255 line
read(10,*) line
do ii =1,255
  if (line(ii:ii) .ne. " " ) then
   istart = ii
 endif
```

and so on.  convert sections of character string to appropriate type.
iarray = int(char(istart:istop)) for example

This is not an official code block. It was meant to convey the logic. User needs to define unit 10 used in read statement and declare other variables for the parser.

This is a character parser when you can check each character in array and convert it to real or integer or whatever. Should work fine on any file.

There are probably much quicker ways to do this now but my method should work fine.

Comment: it was just an example of the logic.  And the only errors are the three dots after if statement which was just there to indicate line to follow and i intentionally left the parenthesis off the if statement to show it wasn't real code. I wasn't trying to write the code for the OP. But i'll correct it in case OP thinks  it legit code.

Comment: There are still errors in char-character and strings requiring : when indexed, but whatever.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see the errors?  could you please point them out just so I know.  If you have time.

Comment: If this is supposed to show how to strip leading spaces from a string using Fortran perhaps you'd be interested in the intrinsic function `adjustl`.

Comment: No, I created a character parser.  you can search for character stings  or spaces, and convert digits in row to a number. Search for line(start:istart+6) = 'vertex'